# C system function causes error 'sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected '

Tags: c, linux, shell, system

I wrote a simple program in C on Linux to delete all the files in a directory except one called `svn` like this:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 
  3 int main()
  4 {
  5     system("rm !(svn)");
  6     return 0;
  7 }
```

But when I compile and run it, the terminal says:  `sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

However, when I type and run the command in the terminal directly, all things are done correctly.
Any ideas?

Comment: which shell are you using? `sh` and `bash` don't support this syntax.

Comment: I think I'm using bash. How can I do what I want in the sh shell syntax?

Comment: @adamk: Bash does support this with the `shopt -s extglob` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is don't use `system`.  Use the Linux system calls to list the files in the directory and remove them using unlink().  Something like:

```
DIR* dirHandle = opendir(dirName);
struct dirent* dirEntry;
while ((dirEntry = readdir(dirHandle)) != NULL)
{
    if (strcmp(dirEntry->d_name, "svn") != 0)
    {
        unlink(dirEntry->d_name);
    }
}
```

Warning: all error handling omitted, not compiled and tested, readdir might return `.` and `..` which also need to be not deleted.

Comment: @wong2: There are many issues associated with `system`, one of which you have already come across.  I seriously would not contemplate it for any production quality code.

Answer (score 4):

You will probably need to use this:

```
system("/bin/bash -c 'rm !(svn)'")
```

or possibly:

```
system("/bin/bash -O extglob -c 'rm !(svn)'")
```

or:

```
system("find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name 'svn' -delete")
```

or similar.

But it's probably better to use [JeremyP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077209/c-system-function-cause-error-sh-syntax-error-unexpected/4077475#4077475).

Answer (score 2):

You must use `sh` shell syntax, you are not doing this.

Comment: Thanks! So how can I do what I want in the sh shell syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I think I would just add the shell to the system command:

```
system("/bin/csh rm !(svn)");
```

or whatever shell you use.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Move file outside directory (f. e. in /tmp or ..), delete all, move it back (do it using several system() calls).

Another approach:

```
find . -prune ! -name svn | xargs /bin/rm -f
```