# system() returns error syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell, system

I want to use one command using the system() API in my C++ code.

The command is:

```
comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u)
```

For more detail about the command, use [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2389/generating-list-of-manually-installed-packages-and-querying-individual-packages).

This command works perfectly when I use the terminal on an Ubuntu 64-bit machine, but when I use in the **system("above command")** API in C++ code, it shows an error, and they are below:

> sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

I am searching on Google and find one solution (*[C system function causes error 'sh: Syntax error: “(” unexpected '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077209/c-system-function-cause-error-sh-syntax-error-unexpected)*), but the accepted solution does task in another way. It's not a solution and other solution not working.

Everyone explains about how to remove this error in the shell script (.sh file), given all solutions might be work on .sh, but they do not work for the system() API. I not able to find how to remove this error in C++ code system() API.

Comment: What if you explicitly attempt to run `bash` with that command? The command `sh` might not be Bash, or it might be Bash without Bash extensions?

Comment: From what I see your command uses process substitution syntax `comm <()`, this is a feature of `bash`, not `sh`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i am open terminal in ubuntu and run "comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u) "  its work but when i use system("sudo comm -23 (<(apt-mark showmanual|sort -u)) (<(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz |sed -n 's/^Package: //p' |sort -u))");api its give error as subject mention.

Comment: @tomix86 right but can you help me how to use it with system() API.

Comment: Try (although this is a bit nasty and may need some tweaking)
`system("/bin/bash -c 'comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n \"s/^Package: //p\" | sort -u)'");`

Comment: Again `sh` is not `bash`. And `bash` is not `sh`. The shell `sh` might be a minimal shell, and it might not even support all POSIX features. The `bash` shell is a very large and complex shell with many non-standard extensions. If you rely on those extension (which I guess `<(...)` is) then you can't use the ordinary shell `sh`. Either you have to modify the command so plain `sh` can run it, or explicitly use `bash` (like in `bash -c "..."`)

Comment: Also note that having `system("sudo ...")` is a security whole large as the side of a barn, just waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, process substitution with `<(...)` is a Bash feature that's not available in vanilla sh. As such, you'll need to explicitly invoke a Bash shell:

```
bash -c "comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u)"
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try:

```
system("bash comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u)");
```